# Autocomplete textbox with multiple values by selecting a value from li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I am trying to develop a autocomplete textbox with multiple values separated by full stop and the element below is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" id="txtSearch"  onkeypress="return searchKeyPress(event);" />
<ul id="ul1" style="display:none;">
<li id="America" >Vendor performance</li>
<li id="Europe" >Raw </li>
</ul>
<ul id="ul2" style="display:none;">
<li id="America">Plant</li>
<li id="America">Material</li>
</ul>
<ul id="ul3" style="display:none;">
<li id="Europe">Ending </li>
<li id="Europe">available</li>
</ul>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
document.getElementById('txtSearch').onkeypress = function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 64 ) {
        $('#ul1').css("display","inline");
        return false;
    }
};
$(document).ready(function(){
var x = "";
$('#ul1 li').click(function(event) 
    { 
    event.preventDefault();
     $('#txtSearch').val($(this).text()+" . ")
    x = $('#txtSearch').val();
     $('#ul1').hide();
     $('#ul2').show();
     $('#ul3').hide();
    });

$('#ul2 li').click(function(){

    $('#txtSearch').val(x+" "+$(this).text())
     $('#ul1').hide();
     $('#ul2').hide();
    })

$('#ul3 li').click(function(){

    $('#txtSearch').val(x+" "+$(this).text())
     $('#ul1').hide();
     $('#ul2').hide();
     $('#ul3').show();
    })
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

it works fine when I select the America but My problem here is when I select Europe I am unable to get the Ending and the available but instead I am getting the plant and material elements in the textbox as which I designed.

Comment: Can you post a demo of this?

Comment: Your `$('#ul3').show()` looks like it is in the wrong spot. Shouldn't it be in the `$('#ul2 li').click` block? Where you have it now, there's no way to click on an `li` element inside `#ul3` to make it show.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this isn't the answer you're waiting for, but jQueryUI contains a great component named "autocomplete" which make exactly what you're trying to do.
[Here is the doc with code examples](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).
You can use categories, remote datasources, multiples values, scrollable results list, etc. It's not as easy as it seems to be (especially when you do remote autocomplete with nodejs and oracle, huhu), but in many cases it's very useful.
All events are handled (click, press a key, mouse scroll, etc) with few code in your page.